# Change a GameObject with script - Increment the scale

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, transform, scale, increment

Just started to learn Unity pathway and currently I am stuck in increment the scale. I followed the unity pathway code but the scale is not working. What is the problem???[Unity pathway code 'balltransform'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kJVUu.png)

```
public class BallTransform : MonoBehaviour {
public Vector3 scaleChange;
void Start()
{   
}
void Update()
{
    transform.localScale += scaleChange;
}
}
```

I try creating a new project but still the same problem., the scale remain unchanged

Comment: The code should be inserted as text, not as image. By any chance would your `scaleChange` variable be an empty `Vector3` (0,0,0) ?

Comment: The code should be inserted as text, not as image. What do you mean?

I am following the unity code "public Vector3 scaleChange;"

Comment: more explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557])

Comment: thanks for the info, this is my first time asking question in stackoverflow

Comment: in general you should probably not call this every frame / make it frame-rate-independent by multiplying by `Time.deltaTime`

Answer (score 0):

Either one of these can be causing it:

1. You did not actually add the script to the appropriate `GameObject`.
2. You did not set `scaleChange` to anything, or set it to `0, 0, 0`.
3. Something else is also modifying the scale.

Comment: 3. Something else is also modifying the scale

- when I set scaleChange to anything or set it to 5, 5, 5. The scaleChange remain the same but on the scale it kept increasing. Althought the scale kept increasing the GameObject remain the same size